# Поле ввода, появление лишнего при увеличении

Tags: html, css

[image: Изображение]

```css
.input1
{
    width: 260px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#input2
{
    height: 180px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: 15px;    
}
```

```html
            <form>
                <input type="text" class="input1"><br>
                <input type="text" class="input1"><br>
                <input type="text" class="input1"><br>
                <input type="text" size="50px" id="input2">
            </form>
```

Почему поле ввода становится серым с дополнительным заголовочным полем?